# Timeout in HTMLCleaner of AsyncTask

Tags: android, parsing, android-asynctask, timeout, htmlcleaner

I using **HTMLCleaner** in **AsyncTask**, for parse site. How to set timeout in HTMLCleaner or timeout AsyncTask? How to make a break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user `Timer` class to set time out period. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: thread.interrupt(); but you must catch the onInterupted exception.

Comment: To break async task. use asynctask.cancel();